# How to scrape price points from a Train operator website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape price points from this [website](https://www.trenitalia.com/): you can select any market combination (for example Torino - Milano), and choose any departure date.

The code I've written is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page_link = "https://www.lefrecce.it/B2CWeb/search.do?parameter=searchOutputViewer&cFID=eHtwQLn2Kks4"
#note that this link is probably expired, you will need to try a new research

page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, "xml")
soup
```

The issue is that when analysing `soup`, there is no trace of price points because it seems that only a part of the webpage is "captured" by bs4. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. for reference, the following image shows what I am supposed to scrape

[image]

Comment: How do you except to scrape when the link in your code is expired?

Comment: As i stated in the question, you have to re-do the research to obtain a new link. It is useless for me to post another link, because it will expire

Comment: Please mention what you are searching like station names , date and other relevant info

Comment: Any station, date is ok, I just need to understand how to scrape this website

Comment: For example you could check Torino Porta Nuova - Milano Centrale tomorrow